# Run a commandline process and get the output while that process is still running?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, unicode

How I can run a commandline process and get the output while that process is still running?

What I mean is to run a CLI process with its own progressbar, the executable itself takes a long time to finish the operation so I want to take that progress information from the own process to display the progress in my application, other way I don't have any info to display a progress until process finishes.

**I'm working in a WindowsForm project, not a Console App.**

I've tried to do the same using FFMPEG.exe (x64) and I can read the "progress" while FFMPEG is running, I can pick the progress from FFMPEG and do what I want, but with this executable I just can't do it and I don't know if is possible.

The program is "dbPowerAmp CoreConverter", it's a music converter, I think the program sends all the outputs in Unicode encoding because to read the output I need to set the output encoding to Unicode.

...Other problem is I can't find a way to read the StandardError output of this process even using Unicode so please if someone can help me with those two problems.

Here is the application: http://www.dbpoweramp.com/install/dMC-R14.4-Ref-Trial.exe

Here is an example output of the program launched directly from CMD:

[image]

(What I need is to pick the progressbar " * " asterisk character amount while process is running to calculate and display that percentage also in my application)

And here is my code:

```
Private Shared CoreConverter As New Process()

Private Shared CoreConverter_Info As New ProcessStartInfo() With { _
              .CreateNoWindow = True, _
              .UseShellExecute = False, _
              .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
              .RedirectStandardError = True _
}

Private Shared Sub Run_CoreConverter()


    ' Just for testing CMD Unicode output:
    '
    ' CoreConverter_Info.FileName = "cmd"
    ' CoreConverter_Info.Arguments = "/U /C C:\CoreConverter.exe " & CoreConverter_Info.Arguments


    CoreConverter_Info.FileName = "C:\CoreConverter.exe"
    CoreConverter_Info.Arguments = String.Format("-infile=""{0}"" -outfile=""{1}"" -convert_to=""mp3 (Lame)""" ..., blah blah blah)
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter.StartInfo = CoreConverter_Info
    CoreConverter.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    CoreConverter.Start()
    CoreConverter.WaitForExit()


    Dim readerStdOut As IO.StreamReader = CoreConverter.StandardOutput

    ' This part works with FFMPEG executable but not with Coreconverter.exe,
    ' What I mean is that the msgbox is displayed when CoreConverter.exe finishes :( 
    ' but with FFMPEG I can read the output while FFMPEG still running.
    While CoreConverter.StandardOutput.EndOfStream = True
        MsgBox(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.ReadLine)
    End While

    If CoreConverter.ExitCode <> 0 Then
        ' Throw New Exception(CoreConverter.StandardError.ReadToEnd)

        ' No way to read the ErrorOutput...
        MessageBox.Show(CoreConverter.StandardError.ReadToEnd, "CoreConverter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        MessageBox.Show(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd, "CoreConverter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub
```

> UPDATE:

Really I'm so desesperated, all of my intents are epic fails, I've tried all what my skills can do (but that is not much).

Even using multithread to run a process in a separated thread while I try to get the output from the main thread I can't try to retrieve the process output until the process exited, it's crazy!, I don't understand why this happens.

Just is a crazy thing where I'm loosing a lot of hours by day, some people tell me that perhaps making a COM Object I can do it, well, I don't want to spent months learning how to make a COM Object just to pick a couple of characters from console, That months learning that would not help me with anything more in my life, simply as that, I need something more basic, maybe the idea of reading the buffer console could work, but sure I would not be able to read the buffer until the process exited, so.

So. What can I do with this damn process?

Just to make more than an update of my question to say my own desesperation words I will paste here a multi thread thing I've tried.

...Like I've said I can't try to read the outputs while process still runing, and the error output just can't be readed (string always is empty) even when the process finishes (with an intentioned error ofcourse).

```
Public Shared error_output As String
Public Shared standard_output As String
Public Shared active As Boolean = False ' CoreConverter Thread is active?

Public Shared MyThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Run_CoreConverter)

Public Shared Sub Convert_To_MP3(ByVal In_File As String, _

' blah blah blah
'Run_CoreConverter()

    MyThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Run_CoreConverter)
    ' MyThread.IsBackground = True
    active = True
    MyThread.Start()
    Get_Output()

End Sub

Public Shared Sub Get_Output()

While active ' While Coreconverter.exe is runing...

    Try
        If Not CoreConverter.HasExited Then
            MsgBox(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd) ' This will not be displayed until process has exited...
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If error_output IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(error_output) ' This will not be displayed until process has exited...
    End If

    If standard_output IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(standard_output) ' This will not be displayed until process has exited...
    End If

End While

MsgBox("end active")

End Sub

Public Shared Sub Run_CoreConverter()
    CoreConverter_Info.FileName = CoreConverter_Location
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter.StartInfo = CoreConverter_Info
    CoreConverter.EnableRaisingEvents = False

    CoreConverter.Start()
    ' CoreConverter.WaitForExit()

    ' Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    ' For x As Integer = 0 To 99999999
    error_output = CoreConverter.StandardError.ReadToEnd
    standard_output = CoreConverter.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
    ' Next

    If CoreConverter.ExitCode <> 0 Then
        Throw New Exception(CoreConverter.StandardError.ReadToEnd)
         MessageBox.Show(CoreConverter.StandardError.ReadToEnd, "CoreConverter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
         MessageBox.Show(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd, "CoreConverter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    CoreConverter.Close()
    active = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Interprocess communications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574

Comment: @xpda Thanks for the information, I read the reference but I do not understand which part of it is that what can help me for this, can you be more specific please?. PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: I've used named pipes to send messages back and forth between applications, but not the others. It's kind of messy to set up, but once you've done it, it works fine. I think you can use some of the other methods to communicate between processes, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: You can try to read from the console buffer (not the output stream). Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355378/read-from-location-on-console-c-sharp (it's c# so you must adapt to vb)

Comment: @Simon Mourier Thankyou, seems a very good idea but I'm not able to translate a complex C# code, I've tried it with online translators but I get a "Invalid controller" exception when trying to use the reader Class, also I need to translate the equivalent of "yield" keyword in VBNET and I think i didn't translated right.

Comment: I've put a VB.NET version here: http://pastebin.com/XYxakDTV

Comment: @Simon Mourier I've tested the code but has the same problem exception "Controller not valid" when trying this part, OD: Windows 8 x64, FW: 4.0, IDE: VS2012, Pryect: WindoesForm. For Each line As String In ConsoleReader.ReadFromBuffer(0, 0, CShort(Console.BufferWidth), 10)
                    MsgBox(line)
                Next

Comment: Don't now what that "controller" thing is.

Comment: @Simon Mourier My IDE throws the exception message in Spanish but I think that message refers to a Handle, maybe console handle?. I did any modification to your pastebin code, just I run it an throws that "controller" exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there may be bugs in dbPowerAmp's encoding. The output looks great in a cmd.exe /u Unicode environment, but it seems when you hook up a .Net Process object, it ends up with null bytes in between characters. You can work around this by discarding null bytes in between good UTF8 characters.

I'm more fluent in PowerShell, so here's what I wrote to prove that this will work.

```
$progressCounter = 0.0
$progressScaleString = "0%-----------25%-----------50%-----------75%-----------100%"
$psi = new-object system.diagnostics.processstartinfo
$psi.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Illustrate\dBpoweramp\CoreConverter.exe"
# Moby Dick audiobook available at <http://ia600208.us.archive.org/0/items/moby_dick_librivox/mobydick_135_melville.mp3>
$psi.arguments =  '-infile="C:\AudioBooks\mobydick_135_melville.mp3" -outfile="c:\AudioBooks\mobydick_135_melville.flac" -convert_to="flac" -encoding="SLOW"'
$psi.StandardOutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$proc = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$proc.StartInfo = $psi
$proc.Start();
#Look for the magic progress bar string
$outputBuf = ""
while($true){ $chr = [char]$proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte(); if($chr -ne [char]0){ $outputBuf += $chr; } if($outputBuf.Contains($progressScaleString)){ break; }else{ sleep .01; }}
#We've seen the progress ruler, now start counting the pips.
while($progressCounter -le 100.0){ $chr = $proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte(); if($chr -lt 0){break;} if([char]$chr -eq [char]"*"){ $progressCounter += 100.0/($progressScaleString.Length+1); write-host $progressCounter; }}
```

Here's my crack at porting this to VB; Just run it on a worker thread and hook PercentDone up to your UI:

```
Public Event PercentDone(ByVal Percent As Float)

Private Shared CoreConverter As New Process()

Private Shared CoreConverter_Info As New ProcessStartInfo() With { _
              .CreateNoWindow = True, _
              .UseShellExecute = False, _
              .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
              .RedirectStandardError = True _
}

Private Shared Sub Run_CoreConverter()

    Dim ProgressScaleString As String = "0%-----------25%-----------50%-----------75%-----------100%"
    Dim ProgressCounter As Float = 0.0

    CoreConverter_Info.FileName = "C:\CoreConverter.exe"
    CoreConverter_Info.Arguments = String.Format("-infile=""{0}"" -outfile=""{1}"" -convert_to=""mp3 (Lame)""" ..., blah blah blah)
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter.StartInfo = CoreConverter_Info
    CoreConverter.Start()

    Dim OutputBuf As String = ""
    Dim chr As Byte;
    While True
      chr = CoreConverter.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte();
      If chr < 0 Then
        Exit While
      ElseIf chr <> 0
        OutputBuf += CType(chr, Char)
      End If
      If OutputBuf.Contains(ProgressScaleString) Then
        Exit While
      Else
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
      End If
    End While

    While ProgressCounter <= 100
      chr = CoreConverter.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte()
      If chr <= 0 Then
        Exit While
      End If
      If chr == CType("*"C, Char) Then
        ProgressCounter += 100.0/($progressScaleString.Length+1)
        RaiseEvent PercentDone(ProgressCounter)
      End If
    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou I will test it when I can, it have much syntax errors I could imagina that you've used a online translator C@ to VB but don't worry just I need some days to test the code. PS: Forgive my english

Answer (score 3):

The process is writing a line of stars (*). I is possible to check it redirecting output to file (`>out.txt`). You should use `CoreConverter.StandardOutput.Read`.

Let's have a form with a multiline TextBox named txtResult and a button cmdStart :

```
Private Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click
        Dim ProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo With
            {.FileName = "C:\dbpower\dBpoweramp\CoreConverter.exe",
             .RedirectStandardOutput = True, .UseShellExecute = False,
             .WorkingDirectory = "C:\dbpower\dBpoweramp", .Arguments = "-infile=""0.mp3"" -outfile=""1.mp3"" -convert_to=""mp3 (lame)"""} '
        Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(ProcInfo)
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        While Not proc.HasExited

            Dim a As String = ChrW(proc.StandardOutput.Read)
            If a = "*" Then
                counter += 1
                txtResult.Text = counter
                Application.DoEvents()
            End If
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(3)
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While

End Sub
```

The progress is written to TextBox as numberes 1-59. You can easily convert it to progress bar.  Plase do not forget to change the .exe path.

Comment: I have added fully functional demo of running CoreConverter.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Finally This is what I've did to solve the problem to be able to retrieve both outputs in a "easy way":

```
#Region " Process Info "

' CoreConverter Process Information.
Private Shared CoreConverter As New Process() With { _
    .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With { _
    .CreateNoWindow = True, _
    .UseShellExecute = False, _
    .RedirectStandardError = True, _
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
    .StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, _
    .StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode}}

#End Region

' Some code
' Blah blah blah...

#Region " Run Converter Procedure "

Private Shared Sub Run_CoreConverter()

    CoreConverter.StartInfo.FileName = CoreConverter_Location
    CoreConverter.Start()

    While Not CoreConverter.HasExited

        OutputCharacter = ChrW(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.Read)

        If OutputCharacter = "*" Then
            CurrentProgress += 1 ' Maximum value is 59, so a ProgressBar Maximum property value would be 59.
            RaiseEvent PercentDone(CurrentProgress, Nothing)
        End If

        If CurrentProgress = 59 Then
            ' I store only the last line 'cause it has interesting information:
            ' Example message: Conversion completed in 30 seconds x44 realtime encoding
            StandardOutput = CoreConverter.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd.Trim
        End If

    End While

    ErrorOutput = CoreConverter.StandardError.ReadToEnd

    Select Case CoreConverter.ExitCode

        Case 0 : RaiseEvent Exited(StandardOutput, Nothing) ' Return StandardOutput
        Case Else : RaiseEvent Exited(ErrorOutput, Nothing) ' Return ErrordOutput

    End Select

    CurrentProgress = 0
    OutputCharacter = Nothing
    StandardOutput = Nothing
    ErrorOutput = Nothing
    ' CoreConverter.Close()

End Sub

#End Region
```

> UPDATE:

Here is the full class if someone need it:

```
#Region " CoreConverter Helper "



' [ CoreConverter Helper ]
'
' // By Elektro H@cker
'
'
' Instructions:
'
' 1. Add the "CoreConverter.exe" into the project,
'    together with the dbPoweramp Effects and Codec folders.
'
' Examples :
'
' -------------------
' CONVERT FILE TO MP3
' -------------------
' CoreConverter.Convert_To_MP3("C:\Input.wav", "C:\Output.mp3", _
'                              CoreConverter.Lame_Bitrate.kbps_320, _
'                              CoreConverter.Lame_Bitrate_Mode.cbr, _
'                              CoreConverter.Lame_Profile.SLOW, _
'                              CoreConverter.Lame_Quality.Q0_Maximum, _
'                              CoreConverter.Lame_Khz.Same_As_Source, _
'                              CoreConverter.Lame_Channels.auto, _
'                              { _
'                                CoreConverter.DSP_Effects.Delete_Output_File_on_Error, _
'                                CoreConverter.DSP_Effects.Recycle_Source_File_After_Conversion _
'                              }, _
'                              False, _
'                              CoreConverter.Priority.normal)
'
' -------------------
' CONVERT FILE TO WAV
' -------------------
' CoreConverter.Convert_To_WAV_Uncompressed("C:\Input.mp3", "C:\Output.wav", _
'                                           CoreConverter.WAV_Uncompressed_Bitrate.Same_As_Source, _
'                                           CoreConverter.WAV_Uncompressed_Khz.Same_As_Source, _
'                                           CoreConverter.WAV_Uncompressed_Channels.Same_As_Source, , False)
'
' -------------------
' CONVERT FILE TO WMA
' -------------------
' CoreConverter.Convert_To_WMA("C:\Input.mp3", "C:\Output.wma", _
'                              CoreConverter.WMA_9_2_BitRates.Kbps_128, _
'                              CoreConverter.WMA_9_2_Khz.Khz_44, _
'                              CoreConverter.WMA_9_2_Channels.stereo, , False)
'
' ------
' EVENTS
' ------
' Public WithEvents Converter As New CoreConverter()
'
' Sub Converter_Progress(Progress As Integer, e As EventArgs) Handles Converter.PercentDone
'     ProgressBar1.Maximum = 59
'     ProgressBar1.Step = 1
'     ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
' End Sub
'
' Sub Converter_Message(Message As String, e As EventArgs) Handles Converter.Exited
'     ProgressBar1.Value = 0
'     MessageBox.Show(Message)
' End Sub



Public Class CoreConverter : Implements IDisposable

#Region " Variables "

    ' <summary>
    ' Gets or sets CoreConverter.exe executable path.
    ' </summary>
    Public Shared CoreConverter_Location As String = ".\CoreConverter.exe"

    ' Stores the CoreConverter process progress
    Private Shared CurrentProgress As Integer = 0

    ' Stores the CoreConverter process StandarOutput
    Private Shared StandardOutput As String = String.Empty

    ' Stores the CoreConverter process ErrorOutput
    Private Shared ErrorOutput As String = String.Empty

    ' Stores the next output character
    Private Shared OutputCharacter As Char = Nothing

    ' Stores the DSP Effects formatted string
    Private Shared Effects As String = String.Empty

#End Region

#Region " Events "

    ' <summary>
    ' Event raised when conversion progress changes.
    ' </summary>
    Public Shared Event PercentDone As EventHandler(Of PercentDoneEventArgs)
    Public Class PercentDoneEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        Public Property Progress As Integer
    End Class

    ' <summary>
    ' Event raised when CoreConverter process has exited.
    ' </summary>
    Public Shared Event Exited As EventHandler(Of ExitedEventArgs)
    Public Class ExitedEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        Public Property Message As String
    End Class

#End Region

#Region " Process Info "

    ' CoreConverter Process Information.
    Private Shared CoreConverter As New Process() With { _
        .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With { _
        .CreateNoWindow = True, _
        .UseShellExecute = False, _
        .RedirectStandardError = True, _
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
        .StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, _
        .StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode}}

#End Region

#Region " CoreConverter Enumerations "

    ' Priority level of CoreConverter.exe
    Enum Priority
        idle
        low
        normal
        high
    End Enum

    ' DSP Effects
    Public Enum DSP_Effects
        Delete_Output_File_on_Error ' Delete failed conversion (not deletes source file).
        Delete_Source_File_After_Conversion ' Delete source file after conversion.
        Recycle_Source_File_After_Conversion ' Send source file to recycle bin after conversion.
        Karaoke_Remove_Voice ' Remove voice from file.
        Karaoke_Remove_Instrument ' Remove instruments from file.
        Reverse ' Reverse complete audio file.
        Write_Silence ' Write silence at start of file.
    End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Codec Enumerations "

    Enum Lame_Bitrate
        kbps_8 = 8
        kbps_16 = 16
        kbps_24 = 24
        kbps_32 = 32
        kbps_40 = 40
        kbps_48 = 48
        kbps_56 = 56
        kbps_64 = 64
        kbps_80 = 80
        kbps_96 = 96
        kbps_112 = 112
        kbps_128 = 128
        kbps_144 = 144
        kbps_160 = 160
        kbps_192 = 192
        kbps_224 = 224
        kbps_256 = 256
        kbps_320 = 320
    End Enum

    Enum Lame_Bitrate_Mode
        cbr
        abr
    End Enum

    Enum Lame_Profile
        NORMAL
        FAST
        SLOW
    End Enum

    Enum Lame_Quality
        Q0_Maximum = 0
        Q1 = 1
        Q2 = 2
        Q3 = 3
        Q4 = 4
        Q5 = 5
        Q6 = 6
        Q7 = 7
        Q8 = 8
        Q9_Minimum = 9
    End Enum

    Enum Lame_Khz
        Same_As_Source
        khz_8 = 8000
        khz_11 = 11000
        khz_12 = 12000
        khz_16 = 16000
        khz_22 = 22000
        khz_24 = 24000
        khz_32 = 32000
        khz_44 = 44100
        khz_48 = 48000
    End Enum

    Enum Lame_Channels
        auto
        mono
        stereo
        joint_stereo
        forced_joint_stereo
        forced_stereo
        dual_channels
    End Enum

    Enum WAV_Uncompressed_Bitrate
        Same_As_Source
        bits_8 = 8
        bits_16 = 16
        bits_24 = 24
        bits_32 = 32
    End Enum

    Enum WAV_Uncompressed_Khz
        Same_As_Source
        khz_8 = 8000
        khz_11 = 11000
        khz_12 = 12000
        khz_16 = 16000
        khz_22 = 22000
        khz_24 = 24000
        khz_32 = 32000
        khz_44 = 44100
        khz_48 = 48000
        khz_96 = 96000
        khz_192 = 192000
    End Enum

    Enum WAV_Uncompressed_Channels
        Same_As_Source
        Channels_1_Mono = 1
        Channels_2_Stereo = 2
        Channels_3 = 3
        Channels_4_Quadraphonic = 4
        Channels_5_Surround = 5
        Channels_6_Surround_DVD = 6
        Channels_7 = 7
        Channels_8_Theater = 8
    End Enum

    Enum WMA_9_2_BitRates
        Kbps_12 = 12
        Kbps_16 = 16
        Kbps_20 = 20
        Kbps_22 = 22
        Kbps_24 = 24
        Kbps_32 = 32
        Kbps_40 = 40
        Kbps_48 = 48
        Kbps_64 = 64
        Kbps_80 = 80
        Kbps_96 = 96
        Kbps_128 = 128
        Kbps_160 = 160
        Kbps_192 = 192
        Kbps_256 = 256
        Kbps_320 = 320
    End Enum

    Enum WMA_9_2_Khz
        Khz_8 = 8
        Khz_16 = 16
        Khz_22 = 22
        Khz_32 = 32
        Khz_44 = 44
        Khz_48 = 48
    End Enum

    Enum WMA_9_2_Channels
        mono
        stereo
    End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Codec Procedures "

#Region " MP3 Lame "

    ' <summary>
    ' Converts a file to MP3 using Lame codec.
    ' </summary>
    Public Shared Sub Convert_To_MP3(ByVal In_File As String, _
                             ByVal Out_File As String, _
                             ByVal Bitrate As Lame_Bitrate, _
                             ByVal Bitrate_Mode As Lame_Bitrate_Mode, _
                             ByVal Encoding_Profile As Lame_Profile, _
                             ByVal Quality As Lame_Quality, _
                             ByVal Khz As Lame_Khz, _
                             ByVal Channels As Lame_Channels, _
                             Optional ByVal DSP_Effects() As DSP_Effects = Nothing, _
                             Optional ByVal Update_Tag As Boolean = True, _
                             Optional ByVal Priority As Priority = Priority.normal, _
                             Optional ByVal Processor As Short = 1)

        If DSP_Effects IsNot Nothing Then

            Effects = String.Empty

            For X As Integer = 0 To DSP_Effects.Length - 1
                Effects &= String.Format(" -dspeffect{0}={1}", _
                                         X + 1, _
                                         Format_DSP_Effect(DSP_Effects(X).ToString))
            Next

        End If

        CoreConverter.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-infile=""{0}"" -outfile=""{1}"" -convert_to=""mp3 (Lame)"" {2} {3} -priority=""{4}"" -processor=""{5}"" -b {6} {7} -encoding=""{8}"" -freq=""{9}"" -channels=""{10}"" --noreplaygain --extracli=""-q {11}""", _
                                       In_File, _
                                       Out_File, _
                                       If(Not Update_Tag, "-noidtag", ""), _
                                       Effects, _
                                       Priority.ToString, _
                                       Processor, _
                                       CInt(Bitrate), _
                                       "--" & Bitrate_Mode.ToString, _
                                       Encoding_Profile.ToString, _
                                       If(Khz = Lame_Khz.Same_As_Source, "", CInt(Khz)), _
                                       If(Channels = Lame_Channels.auto, "", Channels), _
                                       CInt(Quality))
        Run_CoreConverter()

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " WAV Uncompressed "

    ' <summary>
    ' Converts a file to WAV
    ' </summary>
    Public Shared Sub Convert_To_WAV_Uncompressed(ByVal In_File As String, _
                                 ByVal Out_File As String, _
                                 ByVal Bitrate As WAV_Uncompressed_Bitrate, _
                                 ByVal Khz As WAV_Uncompressed_Khz, _
                                 ByVal Channels As WAV_Uncompressed_Channels, _
                                 Optional ByVal DSP_Effects() As DSP_Effects = Nothing, _
                                 Optional ByVal Update_Tag As Boolean = True, _
                                 Optional ByVal Priority As Priority = Priority.normal, _
                                 Optional ByVal Processor As Short = 1)

        If DSP_Effects IsNot Nothing Then

            Effects = String.Empty

            For X As Integer = 0 To DSP_Effects.Length - 1
                Effects &= String.Format(" -dspeffect{0}={1}", _
                                         X + 1, _
                                         Format_DSP_Effect(DSP_Effects(X).ToString))
            Next

        End If

        CoreConverter.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-infile=""{0}"" -outfile=""{1}"" -convert_to=""Wave"" {2} {3} -priority=""{4}"" -processor=""{5}"" -compression=""PCM"" -bits=""{6}"" -freq=""{7}"" -channels=""{8}""", _
                                       In_File, _
                                       Out_File, _
                                       If(Not Update_Tag, "-noidtag", ""), _
                                       Effects, _
                                       Priority.ToString, _
                                       Processor, _
                                       If(Bitrate = WAV_Uncompressed_Bitrate.Same_As_Source, "", CInt(Bitrate)), _
                                       If(Khz = WAV_Uncompressed_Khz.Same_As_Source, "", CInt(Khz)), _
                                       If(Channels = WAV_Uncompressed_Channels.Same_As_Source, "", CInt(Channels)))
        Run_CoreConverter()

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " WMA 9.2 "

    ' <summary>
    ' Converts a file to WMA 9.2
    ' </summary>
    Public Shared Sub Convert_To_WMA(ByVal In_File As String, _
                                 ByVal Out_File As String, _
                                 ByVal Bitrate As WMA_9_2_BitRates, _
                                 ByVal Khz As WMA_9_2_Khz, _
                                 ByVal Channels As WMA_9_2_Channels, _
                                 Optional ByVal DSP_Effects() As DSP_Effects = Nothing, _
                                 Optional ByVal Update_Tag As Boolean = True, _
                                 Optional ByVal Priority As Priority = Priority.normal, _
                                 Optional ByVal Processor As Short = 1, _
                                 Optional ByVal LogFile As String = ".\CoreConverter.log")

        If DSP_Effects IsNot Nothing Then

            Effects = String.Empty

            For X As Integer = 0 To DSP_Effects.Length - 1
                Effects &= String.Format(" -dspeffect{0}={1}", _
                                         X + 1, _
                                         Format_DSP_Effect(DSP_Effects(X).ToString))
            Next

        End If

        CoreConverter.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-infile=""{0}"" -outfile=""{1}"" -convert_to=""Windows Media Audio 10"" {2} {3} -priority=""{4}"" -processor=""{5}"" -codec=""Windows Media Audio 9.2"" -settings=""{6} kbps, {7} kHz, {8} CBR""",
                                       In_File, _
                                       Out_File, _
                                       If(Not Update_Tag, "-noidtag", ""), _
                                       Effects, _
                                       Priority.ToString, _
                                       Processor, _
                                       CInt(Bitrate), _
                                       CInt(Khz), _
                                       Channels.ToString)
        Run_CoreConverter()

    End Sub

#End Region

#End Region

#Region " Run Converter Procedure "

    Private Shared Sub Run_CoreConverter()

        CoreConverter.StartInfo.FileName = CoreConverter_Location
        CoreConverter.Start()

        While Not CoreConverter.HasExited

            OutputCharacter = ChrW(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.Read)

            If OutputCharacter = "*" Then
                CurrentProgress += 1 ' Maximum value is 59, so a ProgressBar Maximum property value would be 59.
                RaiseEvent PercentDone(CurrentProgress, Nothing)
            End If

            If CurrentProgress = 59 Then
                ' I store only the last line 'cause it has interesting information:
                ' Example message: Conversion completed in 30 seconds x44 realtime encoding
                StandardOutput = CoreConverter.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd.Trim
            End If

        End While

        ' Stores the Error Message (If any)
        ErrorOutput = CoreConverter.StandardError.ReadToEnd

        Select Case CoreConverter.ExitCode

            Case 0 : RaiseEvent Exited(StandardOutput, Nothing) ' Return StandardOutput
            Case Else : RaiseEvent Exited(ErrorOutput, Nothing) ' Return ErrordOutput

        End Select

        CurrentProgress = 0
        OutputCharacter = Nothing
        StandardOutput = Nothing
        ErrorOutput = Nothing
        CoreConverter.Close()

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Miscellaneous functions "

    ' <summary>
    ' Checks if CoreConverter process is avaliable.
    ' </summary>
    Public Shared Function Is_Avaliable() As Boolean
        Return IO.File.Exists(CoreConverter_Location)
    End Function

    ' Returns the DSP Effects formatted string
    Private Shared Function Format_DSP_Effect(ByVal Effect As String)

        Select Case Effect
            Case "Reverse" : Return """Reverse"""
            Case "Delete_Output_File_on_Error" : Return """Delete Destination File on Error="""
            Case "Recycle_Source_File_After_Conversion" : Return """Delete Source File=-recycle"""
            Case "Delete_Source_File_After_Conversion" : Return """Delete Source File="""
            Case "Karaoke_Remove_Voice" : Return """Karaoke (Voice_ Instrument Removal)="""
            Case "Karaoke_Remove_Instrument" : Return """Karaoke (Voice_ Instrument Removal)=-i"""
            Case "Write_Silence" : Return """Write Silence=-lengthms={qt}2000{qt}""" ' 2 seconds
            Case Else : Return String.Empty
        End Select

    End Function

#End Region

#Region " Dispose Objects "

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' CoreConverter_Location = Nothing ' Don't touch
        OutputCharacter = Nothing
        StandardOutput = Nothing
        ErrorOutput = Nothing
        CurrentProgress = Nothing
        Effects = Nothing
        CoreConverter.Close()
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class

#End Region
```