# c# console read last written line

Tags: c#, console

Is this possible at all?

I know it is possible to clear last line using `Console.SetCursorPosition`. But cannot find any way to copy what's in the last line.

Why do I need this?: More of a curiosity then real need.

Comment: Linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355378/read-from-location-on-console-c-sharp/12355485#12355485) covers possible way to read Console buffer (PInvoke) - should be enough to get "last line".