# How to check if the cursor is on blank console space(C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, console, cursor-position

I want to check if the cursor is on a text/character or on blank console area.
Is there any way to do this in the console Application in C#?[image]

Just want to know if the yellow cursor (in my case)  is on one of the `@`S or on a blank console space.

Comment: Store the map in an array and check the contents at the location you want to move to

Comment: @Ewan you know whats the method for the checkup? Cursor.Position == array[i,j]? Thanks

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355378/read-from-location-on-console-c-sharp. Basically, you have to keep track off all characters written to the console yourself.

Comment: @JesseGood So i need to follow the link you posted? i didnt understand where is the comparison command? if (array[5,5] == '@') { // Do something } Where is that line comes to play? Thanks.

Comment: It is technically possible but requires pinvoke to call [ReadConsoleOutputCharacter](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleOutputCharacter.html).  You are bound to learn more from doing it @Ewan's way, you can use that practice.

Comment: @HansPassant Whoo, i dont understand a word from that pinvoke. Way out my level. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: @HansPassant From where i start? what libraries do i use for that? What [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] means? |:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works for me is:

```
if (Console.CursorLeft == checkedXPosition && Console.CursorTop == checkedYPosition)
{
  // Do something
}
```