# Read values already printed to the console

Tags: c#, console

This may be completely impossible, but I was wondering if there is a way to read values that the console has already printed. For example, if the console printed

> You are travelling north at a speed of 10m/s

as a result of `Console.WriteLine("You are travelling north at a speed of 10m/s");`, is there a way of reading this line and then, for arguments sake, putting this value in a string?

Basically what I need is to read what has already been outputted to the console, not the user input. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the answers written so far are misunderstand the question. Sounds like OP want's to get _all_ text which is written to console (in somehow) as a programmatically and put it a string variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

Comment: Maybe the second answer from this question is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355378/read-from-location-on-console-c-sharp#answer-12366307

Answer (score 20):

Yes. There is a way. You can [`Console.SetOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Organize your main method as;

```
static void Main()
{
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
         Console.SetOut(stringWriter);

         //All console outputs goes here
         Console.WriteLine("You are travelling north at a speed of 10m/s");

         string consoleOutput = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then `consoleOutput` should have `You are travelling north at a speed of 10m/s`.

Comment: But the message won't show in the actual console window.

Answer (score 14):

If you want still want your output to hit the console, you can use [Console.SetOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) and give it two destinations at once, one being the main console window and the other being your internal store.

You could write a simple helper class like this:

```
public class OutputCapture : TextWriter, IDisposable
{
    private TextWriter stdOutWriter;
    public TextWriter Captured { get; private set; }
    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.ASCII; } }

    public OutputCapture()
    {
        this.stdOutWriter = Console.Out;
        Console.SetOut(this);
        Captured = new StringWriter();
    }
    
    override public void Write(string output)
    {
        // Capture the output and also send it to StdOut
        Captured.Write(output);
        stdOutWriter.Write(output);
    }

    override public void WriteLine(string output)
    {
        // Capture the output and also send it to StdOut
        Captured.WriteLine(output);
        stdOutWriter.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Then in your main code you could wrap your statements as shown below:

```
void Main()
{
    // Wrap your code in this using statement...
    using (var outputCapture = new OutputCapture())
    {
        Console.Write("test");
        Console.Write(".");
        Console.WriteLine("..");
        Console.Write("Second line");
        // Now you can look in this exact copy of what you've been outputting.
        var stuff = outputCapture.Captured.ToString();
    }
}
```

You could change this to have multiple destinations, so you could create an internal store that was something like `List<string>` instead if you wanted to.

**Background:** I did something along these lines (although I didn't keep a copy of the output) when I wanted to get my NHibernate queries to be output into the SQL Output tab in LINQPad. I wrote about it here (there's a Github repo and NuGet packages too): https://tomssl.com/2015/06/30/see-your-sql-queries-when-using-nhibernate-with-linqpad/

Comment: Using the OutputCapture class, nothing seems to be shown in the console when using `Console.ReadKey()` - any suggestions?

Answer (score -4):

It's generally a bad idea to read values from the console unless it is user input. You should put the value into a variable, or if you need to read it at a later date, save it to a file.

```
String a = "You are travelling north at a speed of 10m/s"
Console.WriteLine(a);
//Do anything you want with variable 'a'
```

Answer (score -5):

If you want to save what you are writing to the console, store it in a String variable first and then print the contents of this variable to the console, like so:

```
String consoleOutput = "You are travelling north at a speed of 10m/s"
Console.WriteLine(consoleOutput);
```

That way you can access consoleOutput whenever you want.