# Grab Text From Specific Coordinates In Console

Tags: c#, console

Basically what I need some help with figuring out is how to gather some text from specific coordinates in the console.

Say I have a line of text at position 4,3 and it is 30 characters long. I'm looking for some way to grab just that text for a string. I can navigate there with the `Console.SetCursorPosition`command with those coordinates, so my thinking is that there has to be a way to grab text from those coordinates as well.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may redirect the output so you can have access to all of it as text, then you can parse it however you want. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34944872/4934172) for an example.