# C# How to read/write external console's IO

Tags: c#

There's a **cmd window**.
I want to **read** the **text** in it, **then, write** to it.
The **handle** of the cmd window is **known**,
Use C#'s **Process** is a way, but **RedirectStandardOutput won't work**.

Because **it's running Python** and will **move the cursor**.

I **tried** to use **SendMessage**, but it **only shows** the **title** of that cmd:
*C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd*
But I **want it's content** text.

Is there a way to read what's showing on a running external console?
(for example, cmd console / python console)

**For example:**
*Hello.exe* :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("hello world");
        Console.CursorLeft -= 5;
        Console.Write("you  \n");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello.exe");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output would be:

> hello you
> Hello.exe

Then in *test.exe* :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName.Contains("Hello")).Count() == 0)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "Hello.exe";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            p.OutputDataReceived += delegate (object obj, DataReceivedEventArgs drea)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(drea.Data);
            };
                
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();

            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Test.exe");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output will be something like:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension. (Parameter 'left')
> Actual value was -5.
> at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
> at System.Console.set_CursorLeft(Int32 value)
> at Hello.Program.Main(String[] args)
> hello world
> Test.exe

Is there any fix for it? -v-

Comment: There's not much you can do to get the functionality you seem to want.  The redirected output is a stream, so moving the cursor does not make sense in that context.  What you _can_ do to avoid errors is test for `Console.IsOutputRedirected` and avoid moving the cursor if it is.  You'll also notice that when output is redirected, the cursor position remains at (0, 0), even after writing, so moving it to (-5, 0) is going to fail.

Comment: @sellotape sadly, I cannot change the python file, so the movement of the cursor is a must-have. =(

Comment: So, is the assertion that the python program crashes if its output is redirected? Or do positioning commands just become ignored in the stream reading .. the next question I have; if your c# program is reading in lines, are you certain the python program outputs lines?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm not 100% sure if the python crashes, but after the first line of output, the program stopped showing anything. ||| I ain't sure what is going on in that python program, I only know that it is 100% moving the cursor around to refresh content like a progress bar like "(60/100)" to "(90/100)"

Comment: Do you need the progress bar or is there other output you need? Also, curious what happens if you run it in a Command prompt like `mypyexe.exe >c:\temp\py.txt` - what if anything ends up in the file

Comment: @CaiusJard The progress bar is from python, and I can't change what's in that main.py.
If I run it without Redirect output, everything works fine except I can't get what's on it.

Comment: That comment didn't answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. Much thanks to @**Luuk**.
I found what I need while looking at the post he gave and related questions!

Check : [Read from location on console C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355378/read-from-location-on-console-c-sharp)

Use these (by @**Glenn Slayden**)

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int num);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA(
    IntPtr hStdout,   // result of 'GetStdHandle(-11)'
    out byte ch,      // A̲N̲S̲I̲ character result
    uint c_in,        // (set to '1')
    uint coord_XY,    // screen location to read, X:loword, Y:hiword
    out uint c_out);  // (unwanted, discard)

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW(
        IntPtr hStdout,   // result of 'GetStdHandle(-11)'
        out Char ch,      // U̲n̲i̲c̲o̲d̲e̲ character result
        uint c_in,        // (set to '1')
        uint coord_XY,    // screen location to read, X:loword, Y:hiword
        out uint c_out);  // (unwanted, discard)
```

**I was able to read a printed char using code:**

[image: Example Code Image]

Although in this example, only the first char `h` has been read.
But with this, you will find a way to read all other chars too.
Thus, that's it! Yeah!

OK, but wait, it should be `"external console's IO"`.
Well for this part, the only way I know is that
**you could run an independent Console App as** the `external console app`'s **console**.

(Use create Process like what's in the picture in your independent console, or any other better way)

This is a **ConsoleReader** I made, not pretty, but it works.

```
class ConsoleReader
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int num);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA(
        IntPtr hStdout,   // result of 'GetStdHandle(-11)'
        out byte ch,      // A̲N̲S̲I̲ character result
        uint c_in,        // (set to '1')
        uint coord_XY,    // screen location to read, X:loword, Y:hiword
        out uint c_out);  // (unwanted, discard)

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW(
            IntPtr hStdout,   // result of 'GetStdHandle(-11)'
            out char ch,      // U̲n̲i̲c̲o̲d̲e̲ character result
            uint c_in,        // (set to '1')
            uint coord_XY,    // screen location to read, X:loword, Y:hiword
            out uint c_out);  // (unwanted, discard)

    public static readonly IntPtr stdout = GetStdHandle(-11);
    public static char? ConsoleUnicodeCharAt(uint x, uint y)
    {
        uint coord;
        coord = x;        // loword  <-- X coord to read
        coord |= y << 16;           // hiword  <-- Y coord to read

        var success = ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW(
                stdout,
                out char ch,    // U̲n̲i̲c̲o̲d̲e̲ character result
                1,                  // # of chars to read
                coord,              // (X,Y) screen location to read (see above)
                out _);             // result: actual # of chars (unwanted)

        if (success) { return ch; }
        return null;
    }
    public static char? ConsoleUnicodeCharAt(uint x, uint y,uint read_char_length)
    {
        uint coord;
        coord = x;        // loword  <-- X coord to read
        coord |= y << 16;           // hiword  <-- Y coord to read

        var success = ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW(
                stdout,
                out char ch,    // result: single ANSI char
                read_char_length,                  // # of chars to read
                coord,              // (X,Y) screen location to read (see above)
                out uint actual_char_len);             // result: actual # of chars (unwanted)

        if (success) { return ch; }
        return null;
    }
    public static byte? ConsoleAnsiCharAt(uint x, uint y)
    {
        uint coord;
        coord = x;        // loword  <-- X coord to read
        coord |= y << 16;           // hiword  <-- Y coord to read

        var success = ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA(
                stdout,
                out byte ch,    // result: single ANSI char
                1,                  // # of chars to read
                coord,              // (X,Y) screen location to read (see above)
                out _);             // result: actual # of chars (unwanted)

        if (success) { return ch; }
        return null;
    }
    public static string GetLineAt(uint y, Encoding encoding)
    {
        uint i = 0;
        var line_index = y;
        if (encoding == Encoding.Unicode)
        {
            List<char> line_chars = new List<char>();
            char? ch;
            while ((ch = ConsoleUnicodeCharAt(i++, line_index)) != null) { line_chars.Add((char)ch); if (ch == '\0') { break; } }
            return new string(line_chars.ToArray());
        }
        else if (encoding == Encoding.ASCII)
        {
            List<byte> line_bytes = new List<byte>();
            byte? b;
            while ((b = ConsoleAnsiCharAt(i++, line_index)) != null) { line_bytes.Add((byte)b); if (b == byte.MinValue) { break; } }
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(line_bytes.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static string GetLineAt_Unicode(uint y, uint trylength) //trylength is for first char
    {
        uint i = 0;
        var line_index = y;
        List<char> line_chars = new List<char>();
        char? ch;
        while((ch = ConsoleUnicodeCharAt(i++, line_index, trylength) ).HasValue)
        {
            line_chars.Add((char)ch);

            var size = GetCharSize(ch.Value);
            i += size - 1;

            if ((char)ch == '\0') { break; }
        }
        return new string(line_chars.ToArray());
    }
    public static string GetCurrentLine(Encoding encoding)
    {
        return GetLineAt((uint)Console.GetCursorPosition().Top, 
             encoding);
    }
    public static string GetCurrentLine_Unicode(uint try_char_length)
    {
        return GetLineAt_Unicode((uint)Console.GetCursorPosition().Top, try_char_length);
    }
    public static uint GetCharSize(char c)
    {
        var b = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
        uint size = (uint)b.Length;
        for (int i=b.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if (b[i] != 0) { break; }
            size--;
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a simple python script which reproduces this.

```
def moveleft(y):
    print("\033[%dD" %(y), end="")

print("Hello World",end="")
moveleft(5)
print("you  ")
print("Hello.exe")
```

When executing it, the output looks like:

```
Hello you
Hello.exe
```

When doing `python hello.py > hello.txt`, and looking at the `hello.txt` file, it looks like this:

```
Hello World<esc>[5Dyou  
Hello.exe
```

Where `<esc>` is a representation of the Escape character.

When your python script uses the same way as above script to position the cursor, you should not have a problem.

When other means of cursor positioning are used, you are "out of luck".
Maybe some help would be [Read values already printed to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920124/read-values-already-printed-to-the-console), but I do not know how to do that on a remote console.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your answer, I looked at your related post, then I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355378