# Get Value from Console Application inside C# Variable

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am working on a console application that has some data already written into it.

Let's say following data is written inside my console application,

> This is the data written in Console Application at the start of
>   Console Application

Now, I want to read this data inside C# Variable. Let's suppose I want to read something available at coordinates (2,0) which will be in this case 'i'.

Just like i am able to write into console after setting the cordinates by using the following code,

```
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 6);

        Console.Write("Test Data");
```

In similar way, how can i read this data?

Comment: Reading text output is trivial (and shown in every sample for `Process.Start`), but what you are asking (read output that use console positioning to construct text and not regular output stream) is not possible - see what I believe is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355378/read-from-location-on-console-c-sharp).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want to read from specific coordinates